# Why is everything rainbow-colored in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, rainbows

I'm using this on an older laptop which for some reason refuses to update to Service Pack 1 so I can't run the latest version of Unity. Right now I'm running an older version and I've tried almost every 2017 version, they all have this problem. All my materials have a kind of red-green-blue rainbow effect. By switching from version to version I've found this one has the least amount of "rainbowing" but it's still doing it. How do I make the materials load normally? Bear in mind, this is using just the default material so it SHOULDN'T be doing this.

[image: This cube is supposed to be a solid color for example]

Answer (score 0):

Shader rendering is done on the GPU, and you say that you use an old laptop. My guess would be that you need to update the drivers of your graphic card. If this doesn't work, maybe your card is too old to run these shaders.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Edit -> Graphics Emulation**

change Shader Hardware Tier to Tier 1 , i think that would solve your problem.